# I have two tables to join and i need to substitute for {b} values of column a from another column named b

Tags: pandas

table err:

| err id | err info |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | has a decision of {decision} on the {tab} tab of the content |
| 10002 | has a decision of {decision} on the {tab} of the items |

table main:

| err id | tab | decision | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | a | remove | 1 |
| 10001 | b | keep | 2 |

I need the result table after join  on err id to be like below: i.e UPDATE {decision} from the value in decision column and UPDATE {tab} from the value in tab column

| err id | tab | decision | id | err info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | a | remove | 1 | has a decision of **remove** on the **a** tab of the content |
| 10001 | b | keep | 2 | has a decision of **keep** on the **b** of the items |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

err_data = {"errid": [10001, 10002],
            "errinfo": ["has a decision of {decision} on the {tab} tab of the content",
                        "has a decision of {decision} on the {tab} of the items"],
            }
table_data = {"errid": [10001, 10002],
              "tab": ["a", "b"],
              "decision": ["remove", "keep"],
              "id": ["1", "2"],
              }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(err_data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
# above can be replace by read csv
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['errid'])
errinfo_new = []
for tup in zip(df3['decision'], df3['tab'], df3['errinfo']):
    decision = tup[0]
    tab = tup[1]
    errinfo = tup[2]
    errinfo = errinfo.replace("{decision}", decision).replace("{tab}", tab)
    errinfo_new.append(errinfo)
df3 = df3.drop(columns=['errinfo'])
df3.insert(4, 'errinfo_new', errinfo_new)
print(df3)
```